# How do I get my react project running after cloning it from github as I receive errors after running npm install command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

So I begin by running git clone http://...........
and it downloads the project successfully

Then I run cd to change directories. That works!

I run npm install in the directory and the following errors are displayed in the cmd line

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Home\Documents\Ctr-Alt-Elite/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "<" (0x3C) in JSON at position 625 while parsing near "...us-bar\": \"~1.1.0\",\r\n<<<<<<< HEAD\r\n    \"f..."
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-08T17_53_50_035Z-debug.log
```

Below is the debug.log file

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'start'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.2
2 info using node@v16.13.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 9ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Home\Documents\Ctr-Alt-Elite\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Home\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 21ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 22ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 6ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 7ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 52ms
27 timing command:run-script Completed in 8ms
28 timing command:start Completed in 26ms
29 verbose stack JSONParseError: Unexpected token "<" (0x3C) in JSON at position 625 while parsing near "...us-bar\": \"~1.1.0\",\r\n<<<<<<< HEAD\r\n    \"f..."
29 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json-fast\index.js:11:61
29 verbose stack     at async RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:87:19)
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\Home\Documents\Ctr-Alt-Elite
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
33 verbose node v16.13.1
34 verbose npm  v8.1.2
35 error code EJSONPARSE
36 error path C:\Users\Home\Documents\Ctr-Alt-Elite/package.json
37 error JSON.parse Unexpected token "<" (0x3C) in JSON at position 625 while parsing near "...us-bar\": \"~1.1.0\",\r\n<<<<<<< HEAD\r\n    \"f..."
38 error JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
38 error JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
39 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Are there any installation instructions that come with the project?

Comment: No.  A few days ago I was able to simply download the zipped project folder from gitlab and extracted it to the proper directory and it worked then. I could npm install followed by npm start and the project would work. Since then new files have been committed and neither the git clone/npm install option (this option never worked for me with this project) NOR the download zipped folder/npm (which only worked a couple days ago) install option work for me now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone committed a merge conflict in package.json, making the JSON invalid. To fix the issue, go to package.json and resolve the conflict. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/merge-conflicts-what-they-are-and-how-to-deal-with-them/#what-merge-conflicts-really-look-like-in-git) is an article explaining all you need about merging manually. The gist of it is that a conflict looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
// Here is the code for your version/branch
=======
// Here is the version from the version/branch you're merging in
>>>>>>> <branch-/tagname or commitref>
```

Then you need to manually decide what should be kept from the two versions, and of course, remove the markers.

Comment: Running `git mergetool` won't help after the error has been committed. This isn't a Git issue in any case -- it's a matter of whoever is providing the software not actually testing what they put up.

Comment: Ah. Didn't think about that. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out